# createSocket() returns after a long time

Tags: java, ssl

My code suppose to initiate an SSL socket with some peer, extract the certificates and close the sockets.

The problem is that, `createSocket()` seems to block for a long time. How can I set a reasonable timeout?

Here's my full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SSLContext sslCtx;
        sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

        sslCtx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {

            private X509Certificate[] accepted;

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) {
                accepted = xcs;
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return accepted;
            }
        }}, null);


        System.out.println("start ....");
        try (SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslCtx.getSocketFactory().createSocket("156.70.54.68", 443)) {
            sslSocket.setSoTimeout(5_000);
            Certificate[] certificates = sslSocket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
            System.out.println(certificates.length);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling socket(String, int) call socket() and then after, define the timeout, and call connect(InetSocketAddress, int) which takes an int for timeout.

```
    try (SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslCtx.getSocketFactory().createSocket()) {
        sslSocket.setSoTimeout(5_000);
        Certificate[] certificates = sslSocket.getSession().getPeerCertificates();
        System.out.println(certificates.length);
        sslSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("156.70.54.68", 443), 5_000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Worked - Thanks!